# How to efficiently get and set bitmap pixels

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, pixel

I am currently making an app that involves altering the RGB values of pixels in a bitmap and creating a new bitmap after.

My problem is I need help increasing speed of this process. (It can take minutes to process a bitmap with `inSampleSize = 2` and forever to process an `inSampleSize = 1`) Right now, I am using the `getPixel` and `setPixel` methods to alter the pixels and believe these two methods are the root of the problem as they are very inefficient. The `getPixels` method isn't suitable as I am not altering each pixel in order (ex. getting a pixel and changing a radius of 5 pixels around it to the same colour) unless anyone knows of a way to use `getPixels` (perhaps be able to put the pixels in a 2D array).

This is part of my code:

```
public static final alteredBitmp(Bitmap bp)
{


 //initialize variables
 // ..................


  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int left = Math.max(0, x - RADIUS);
        int right = Math.min(x + RADIUS, width - 1);
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {

            int top = Math.max(0, y - RADIUS);
            int bottom = Math.min(y + RADIUS, height - 1);

            int maxIndex = -1;

            for (int j = top; j <= bottom; j++) {
                for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {

                    pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(i, j);

                    //get rgb values
                    //make changes to those values
                }
            }
        }
     }

     //set new rgb values


     bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(r, g, b));

     //return new bitmap
```

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: you can get the imageview dimensions and make your bitmap relevant to it

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't want to distort the aspect ratio of the original bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider looking at RenderScript, which is Android's high performance compute framework. As you are iterating over width x height number of pixels and altering each one which in a modern device could be around a million pixels or higher, doing it in a single thread can take minutes. RenderScript can parallelize operations over CPU or the GPU where possible.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/levels-in-renderscript.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

Google IO 2013 session:
https://youtu.be/uzBw6AWCBpU

RenderScript compatibility library: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html

Comment: +Morrison Thanks for the links! They are very helpful :)